# How to embed only certain lines from a gist?

Tags: github, gist

Gist lets you embed a gist in a web page:

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/dyoo/4627246.js"></script>
```

I was hoping I could have it display just a line range subset. (Use case: Write some code for a blog post in a single gist. Reference certain lines throughout the blog post discussing those lines.)

Is this possible?  I can't find it documented, but is there some way to do it?

---

As an example of how I thought it *might* work, GitHub supports URIs with line numbers. For example, the `#L4-L8` anchor in this:

```
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/base-css.html#L4-L8
```

I realize GitHub shows *all* lines with just those lines *highlighted*. Whereas I'm asking how to *show* just certain lines from a Gist. I mention this just for-example, how I guessed it might work.

---

> p.s According to [How do I embed a single file from a GitHub gist with the new gist interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface), it sounds like this recently moved in the opposite direction from what I'm asking: The ability to embed just one file from a gist recently disappeared. I want to display just certain lines from just one file. But I wanted to ask anyway. Also I think this is a distinct question from that, which is why I posted this instead of commenting the existing question.

Comment: Actually the old method using the `?file=` parameter still works but does not seem be implemented in the UI any longer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gist API doesn't provide any such way to embed part of a gist. However you can do it yourself with javascript in your end.
there is a good library you can use:

https://github.com/kashif-umair/gist-embed/

You can embed parts of a gist with this.

Comment: This is a fork of https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed which is regularly updated and includes a bunch of other features.

Comment: 2014-06-15: Updated answer's link to point to base over out of date fork: https://github.com/kashif-umair/gist-embed/

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do it without libraries

Copy the embed and append to the `src` attribute the following `?file=the-name-of-your-file`

---

A real example

The gist is https://gist.github.com/dianjuar/8df3873cd9db49b7fcd86e74b57dd848

So, to show in an embed only the file called `circleci-useful-env-variables-pr.sh`, I must

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/dianjuar/8df3873cd9db49b7fcd86e74b57dd848.js?file=circleci-useful-env-variables-pr.sh"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is this:

http://gist-it.appspot.com/

```
# Embed the file robertkrimen/gist-it-example/example.js
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/github/robertkrimen/gist-it-example/blob/master/example.js"></script>

# Embed without a footer
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/github/robertkrimen/gist-it-example/blob/master/example.js?footer=0"></script>

# Show only the first and second line
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/github/robertkrimen/gist-it-example/blob/master/example.js?slice=0:1"></script>
```