# Can README.md get the github r package version number?

Tags: r

R package README.md files can have those nice CRAN version badges from [Metacran](http://www.r-pkg.org/services) (see e.g. https://github.com/hadley/devtools). I am wondering:

Can I also show the current development version (as per DESCRIPTION line "Version: ___")?

I can get started if line numbers are known:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28332095/1587132

Rstudio renders it nicely as html if I use

```
<script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/github/brry/berryFunctions/blob/master/DESCRIPTION?slice=3:5"></script>
```

However, it seems to be completely ignored in https://github.com/brry/berryFunctions#intro

Comment: Seems I'm not alone wanting similar things: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/172#issuecomment-33241601