# Single file of a multi-files gist on Medium.com

Tags: gist

Does anyone know a way to include a single file of a multi-file gist into a medium post?

I've tried, without luck, the solutions proposed here:

- [How do I embed a single file from a GitHub gist with the new gist interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface)
- [Yes, we get the gist](https://blog.medium.com/yes-we-get-the-gist-1c2a27cdfc22)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## 2020 - It is possible!

There is a way for that **without** using `<script>`, but it's kind of tricky:

> ⚠️ The order matters!

1. Copy the (multi-file) gist path. e.g.:

```
https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/91e34fd0e987fe7ce801936dc6ece0e8
```

---

2. Paste it somewhere else than the Medium article. Like an online textbox:

[image: Demo]

<sub>⚠️ Do not hit search or return button</sub>

---

3. Append the query param for the file to the URL. e.g:

```
https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/91e34fd0e987fe7ce801936dc6ece0e8?file=Interface.swift
```

<sub>Note that `?file=Interface.swift` at the end of the URL, right?</sub>

---

4. Copy and paste it in the article and see the magic

#### An article using this method:

**[Implement Custom Activity Indicator With The SwiftUI](https://mojtabahs.medium.com/implement-custom-activity-indicator-in-the-swiftui-9e0f3d4155e4)**

---

## The MOST Important note that MUST be considered:

⚠️ Note that you **MUST** copy an unformatted plain text in the medium and **MUST NOT** edit the URL after pasting it in the Medium! You can copy the link in an online textbox like google.com and after appending the query, copy it back and paste it in the Medium.

Answer (score 10):

The [Medium API for posts](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#33-posts) refers to "[Accepted markup for Medium’s Publishing API](https://blog.medium.com/accepted-markup-for-medium-s-publishing-api-a4367010924e)" and the [markdown syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).
None of them includes a `<script>`, needed to [include a Gist single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14267385/6309)

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/<id>.js?file=afile" type="text/javascript" />
```

The only workaround is to generate the article content, included the gist file, and publish the built text with everything in it.
If the Gist changes though, that means the article has to be updated.

[Phelipe Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4195562/phelipe-rocha) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809530/single-file-of-a-multi-files-gist-on-medium-com/47125311?noredirect=1#comment94453656_47125311) the article "[Dealing with Code on Medium](https://medium.com/@egonelbre/dealing-with-code-on-medium-c40016e8b1f3)" from [Egon Elbre](https://twitter.com/egonelbre)

> The least frustrating approach I’ve found was using code screenshots. Obviously, this is very annoying for readers.

I would add: combining a screenshot with an HTML link referencing the gist file might be an acceptable workaround (notwithstanding the gist changes, which would mean updating the screenshots).

Comment: Or create a new gist for ever single file :-(

Comment: This should work irrespective of where you host it; it's a simple `js` file that gets loaded; and if multi files work on Medium, the `?file.extension` simply queries for that one particular file. Should work.