# Trying to embed a gist in an Angular 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, gist

Is there a way to embed a gist, which is given as a script:

```
<script 
src="https://gist.github.com/Slugpotato/bce9877d9c38d7415960e18fadc4efd7.js">
</script>
```

in Angular 4? I'm creating tutorials so I don't want to keep every gist in the index.html file but rather in the typescript file associated with each component if possible. Sorry if this is a repeat question, I just can't seem to find an easy answer for this.

Edit: To clarify, Angular doesn't allow  tags in the html templates of each component, so I was wondering how one can embed gists, which come in the form of a script, in a component's typescript file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I embed a single file from a GitHub gist with the new gist interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface)

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm asking how to wrap a gist in typescript or rather how to include it in Angular. That question is just asking how to edit the source in the script to only include a specific file in the gist.

Comment: sorry, it is just not very clear at all what it is you are asking - that question/answer is specifically about how to include an embedded gist - i.e. add a query string like ?file=myFile.blah

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to clarify further. Angular doesn't allow <script> tags in the html templates of each component, so I was wondering how one can embed gists, which come in the form of a script, in a component's typescript file. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone still trying to do this, I found an excellent npm package on github that allows one to embed gists in Angular 4:

https://github.com/jasonhodges/ngx-gist

Comment: This package works with bugs of height. I faced scroll every time.