# How to create language selection wrapper from a gist script?

Tags: javascript, html, gist

I have a Gist file written in different languages all do the same thing.

So, I would like to create a language select option similar to [Google docs documentation](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/samples/output-json#java).
[image]

Is it possible to create such a wrapper class that accepts a Gist script tag and display as above?

As in [embed single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface), I tried different query command like <script src="https://gist.github.com/gistid.js?language=python">, but none of them work.

Comment: Github has an API now including [calls that retrieve gists](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/gists). However it doesn't have the ability to retrieve just one file from a gist containing multiple files let alone filtering by language. So, to answer your question, yes it's possible to do what you want, but you'll have to do the processing yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the processing code that I ended up with.

With some CSS + javascript hide and toggle logic, it would work like google docs documentation.

I'd appreciate it if anyone updates this answer, with css or js.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def render_gist_by_file(gist_id):
    result = requests.get(f'https://gist.github.com/{gist_id}.js', headers=git_credential)
    if result.text.startswith("<!DOCTYPE html>"):
      return None

    result = result.text
    result = result.replace("\\/", "/").replace("\\&", "&").replace("\\$", "$").replace("\\<", "<").replace("\\`", "`").replace("\\n", "\n").replace('\\"', '"')
    result = html.unescape(result)
    result = result.split("document.write('")[-1][:-3]

    bs = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")

    for tag in bs.find_all(class_="gist"):
      file_box = tag.find(class_="file-box")
      root = tag.find(class_="file-box")
      toggle_div = bs.new_tag('div', attrs={"class": "gist-meta"})

      for i, d in enumerate(tag.find_all(class_="file")):
        d["class"] = f"file gist-toggle gist-id-{gist_id}"
        if i != 0:
          file_box.append(d)  # combine to first table

      for d in tag.find_all(class_="gist-meta"):
        siblings = list(d.next_elements)
        file_id, file_name = siblings[4].attrs["href"].split("#")[-1], siblings[5]
        gist.file_names.append(file_name)
        toggle_a = bs.new_tag('a', attrs={"id": file_id, "class": f"gist-toggle gist-id-{gist_id}", "onclick": f"toggle('gist-id-{gist_id}', '{file_id}')", "style": "padding: 0 18px"})
        toggle_a.append(file_name)
        toggle_div.append(toggle_a)
        d.extract()  # remove bottom nav

      root.insert(0, toggle_div)
      for d in islice(tag.find_all(class_="gist-file"), 1, None):
        d.extract()  # remove except first
    gist.html = str(bs)
    return gist
```