# Recommend a site to share sample data with vega-editor to overcome the problem of "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present"?

Tags: vega-lite

To demonstrate my problems, I'd share the sample data at a host, to make vega-lite specification more readable.
I tried [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com), and dropbox.com.
But I always run into the issue of "Loading failed".
Upon examination of the console output, I found the root cause is

> "Access to fetch at https://gist.github.com from origin
> 'https://vega.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

I wonder if there is a site for public sharing/hosting temporarily my sample data that works with vega-editor?

I had wished that given vega-editor is hosted at github.io domain, it might be easier to address the issue.

EDIT: adding the sample specification with data url to gist.github.com
It has the problem.

```
{
  "data": {"url": "https://gist.github.com/yubrshen/37479eb7637007e1ca9d703a5a56a479"},
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "estimating-date-time", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "ETA-variance", "type": "quantitative"},
    "row": {"field": "PLATFORM"}
  }
}
```

EDIT1: try to expression the value to "url" appearing more like a file path:

```
{
  "data": {"url": "https://gist.github.com/yubrshen/37479eb7637007e1ca9d703a5a56a479?file=variances.json"},
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "estimating-date-time", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "ETA-variance", "type": "quantitative"},
    "row": {"field": "PLATFORM"}
  }
}
```

but the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that github pages is an option; for example the following [works in the vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJghgLhIFygG4QDYFcCmBneBtUAHvAAwB0ArADQgCeJF1AlgLYDm8IAFlFAA5ZwA9IMQZWEUq0ZROaAEalGAexFiIAWkgwsGKFkFaIggGbGlBUrwB27AL6VC8AIwNaz1y3ZwuPfkNXiktKyCsoBGoY6egbQRlLMvJY2IPaOcABMrnQZHmwc3HwCwqKBUjLyiiolEbFR+oaCAOwAXoyJ1nYAuvYgzBAATgDW8KBQNLwYHCwQrJPUAO6MYDLw5MTUnBiMrNyrxD0YVgDGSmCMyQggRJfGjBgoYBxE1GMTHACOaBBWUNLQjKIUtRsqBbvdHt46C9xpNvJ9vr8YL9AT00P0UCMQGCHlM8tC3t4rEpmOdUClbLYgA):

```json
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 0.5, "y": 0.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/ffox.png"},
      {"x": 1.5, "y": 1.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/gimp.png"},
      {"x": 2.5, "y": 2.5, "img": "https://vega.github.io/vega-datasets/data/7zip.png"}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {"type": "image", "width": 50, "height": 50},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"},
    "url": {"field": "img", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your working example, I've added the failing specification. I wonder if the difference between vega.github.io and gist.github.com matters?

Comment: Yes, I think the difference probably matters. But your example has other issues: it is a link to a gist containing JSON, not a link to a JSON file. The two are not interchangeable.

Comment: Oh, that's might be my problem. I haven't figured out how to express the path to the JSON from based the gist address. Do you know how to?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206307/how-do-i-embed-a-single-file-from-a-github-gist-with-the-new-gist-interface
I change it to https://gist.github.com/yubrshen/37479eb7637007e1ca9d703a5a56a479?file=variances.json
but still got the same error.

Comment: What you need is the Raw URL (click `Raw` at the top of that page) but it suffers from the same CORS header issue that you originally asked about. You cannot use data hosted at github.com within vega-lite charts hosted at another domain.

Comment: I can confirm that GitHub pages works. You have to create a GitHub repository, then convert it to a GitHub pages site. You can then link to the data in vega-lite. Another option is to search for CORS proxy, which should let you proxy data from anywhere.